# how to out put ../images.. for sprite in compass sass?

Tags: css, compass-sass, css-sprites

how to out put ../images.. for sprite in compass sass?
and does any one know where can i find documents of senieor toturial of compass sass sprite? such as sprite-url function which can not be found in official website.

```
--css
--sass
    --test.scss
--images
--sprite-images
    --icons
        --a.png
        --b.png

.test.scss codes:
-----------------------
$sprite: sprite-map("icons/*.png");
.hello{
    background-image : sprite-url($sprite);
}

outputs
------------------------
.hello{
    background-image : url('/images/icons-s2c837140f3.png');
}

<!-- but I want to output  -->
.hello{
    background-image : url('../images/icons-s2c837140f3.png');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: `http_path = '../'` may indeed be what you need.

See also `generated_images_dir` here: http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/

If you haven't set a custom project_path or project_dir, you should be able to just set it to `../images`, though you may also need to set `relative_assets` to true.

And there isn't much else you need to know about sprite-url and such helpers aside from what you'll find here: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/ or in the [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues).

Comment: Beat me to it! This is one of the first issues I ran into with Compass and, oddly, finding the configuration reference from the Compass site itself is a total PITA.

Comment: Agreed. Why config reference would be in tutorials is beyond me.

Comment: Maybe it's their way of testing you before you go running off to the forums? Of course, they just end up here instead : P

Comment: tank you ! add( http_path = "../") and ok